# MapKit Compass is shown when rotating

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have a question regarding **`MapKit`**. 
In `regionDidChangeAnimated` I am checking if, is there `MKCompassView` class subview. If does, I am changing the frame. 
This is my way to change the position of compass. 
It works as expected, however, when I am touching to rotate, the compass begins to be visible in default position, when I stop touching, it's going to provided location. How can I achieve movement before compass will be visible at all.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

    for (UIView *temp in self.mapView.subviews){
        if([temp isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MKCompassView")]){
            temp.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 36, 35);
       }
    } }
```

Comment: Google: https://1024kilobyte.com/custom-compass-position-in-mkmapview/ Instead of changing the frame of the compass when the region changes, change it as soon as your map is created by subclassing `MKMapView` and setting it's frame in `layoutSubviews`

Comment: It was very helpful, just translated it to Obj-C version and it's working as expected. It's a good question why Apple closed API for MKCompassView for common use????